# Adding references to IronPython classes

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about adding references to IronPython classes. I have a project with a 100 of *.py files which are placed in one folder, let's say 'Code'. And these files are dependent between themselves. I found out that to add reference to another python class I can use simple:

```
from PythonClass import PythonClass
```

But if I have about 20 dependencies I wouldn't like to write this identical code but with different classes names. I added init.py file to my Code folder and wrote at the top of the class from that folder:

```
from Code import *
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way to add to one class references to all other classes which are placed in the same directory?